# Applying communication rules and limits for journeys across multipele Businss Units (in Salesforce Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, sfmc-business-unit

i have a question and not sure if there is a straighforward solution.

We have identical customer lists in multiple business units (one for each brand). We want to set communication rules and limits to avoid overlap/over-emailing over any particular day or week. We do not have a shared content calendar since the brands operate relatively separate.

Is there a setting or feature that can set communication rules/limits for shared contacts across BUs, say at the parent BU level?

The journeys across BUs are not integrated in any way. Would it make more sense to integrate them somehow (but how?)

Is there a solution utilizing data extensions/lists?

Appreciate the helpful insights here.